# SSRS tables side by side

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Ive got an RS report set up and i have 2 separate tables, one is a 10 column table with 6 of the columns hidden until expanded on. I also have a table next to this one, however this table sits at the far end of the first table as if it was all expanded. What i want to do is have it so that the 2nd table sits on the end of the first table and moves when the fields are expanded or collapsed! Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to get it to do exactly what I needed, took a bit of trial and error but it was actually the chart that sat below the two tables that was affecting the position of the second table. I put the two table inside a rectangle sitting side by side and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try to show top @number rows and not hide unnecessary ones. and by expanding change @number.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you want. Moving elements like that would require SSRS to sometimes move your table on the next page when it goes too far on the right.